# Meteor Account Creation using Token

Tags: meteor

I am using Meteor to create a web app that people can use to sign up for a daily lunchtime game of football at work.  I want to ensure that the only people who are able to create a User Account are those that actually work in my establishment.  The easiest way of doing this is ensuring that they on account creation they enter a password (I will use the word 'token' but I'm not sure if this is the best description) given them by another member of staff.  I know this is not the most secure method but it works!

What would be the best way of doing this in Meteor?  At the moment I am planning to use a custom form (Inputs: Username, Password, Token).  As part of the validation I would use a Method to compare the token with a hashed token stored in settings.json (as a private key) and, if it passes, allow Accounts.createUser to create the account with the other data.

I have no code to show as I am in the planning stage at the moment, but would there be any security issues with this (or is there an easier method that I am just missing?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sign-up code` feature in `accounts-entry` package.

Find the package [here](https://atmospherejs.com/joshowens/accounts-entry)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I don't think that works with React Router, which I use.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be that you take two fields when login username and password and after checking the fields you can give a token generated by jwt-token package on successful login and store it in local storage.
After that you can verify that token on each request or on route and for logout you just need to remove the token from the local storage.

[jwt-token package](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken)